# Pure function in Nest

Tags: pure-function

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
Table[Nest[# + 0.1 * -i *  #^2 &, 2, 1] , {i, 0, 0.5, 0.1}]
(* {2., 1.96, 1.92, 1.88, 1.84, 1.8} *)
```

The problem is that it keeps using 2 in the argument instead of the last result. Normally the first parameter is the starting point, when using the pure function.

The output should be something like

```
(* {2., 1.96, 1.883, 1.777, 1.651, 1.514} *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mathematica* does do the right thing. For your purpose, `Fold` or `FoldList` should be used.

```
FoldList[#1 + 0.1*-#2*#1^2 &, 2.0, Range[0.1, 0.5, 0.1]]
```

*Mathematica* gives

```
{2.,1.96,1.88317,1.77678,1.6505,1.51429}
```

Exactly what you want.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought i was possible to use Nest(List) here, because if you nest 3 or 4 times fx you use the last result each time. But im still a rookie it appears :)